# Shapefile downloaded from GeoServer has attribute data (in Farsi) changed?

Tags: geoserver, shapefile, wfs, attribute-table, download

I added many shapefiles and PostgreSQL database into GeoServer!

However, when I downloaded this Shapefiles again why is my attribute data not legible in Farsi characters?

[image][image][image]

Comment: how did you add the shapefiles to postgis?

Comment: I guess your database columns are of a wrong data type. Probably you need to select UTF8 as the base encoding when doint initdb. See http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/multibyte.html .